# jQuery .on() method for AJAX populated select box not working with iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, ajax

I am using some AJAX to dynamically populate select boxes based on the previous select box, which targets `<select id="exam_level">` in this case

```
jQuery('#exam_level').on('change', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    var $examLevel=jQuery('#exam_level').val();
    jQuery( "#loading-animation").show();
    // call ajax
    jQuery("#exam_subject").empty();
    jQuery.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",       
            type:'POST',
            data:'action=my_special_ajax_call&exam_levelid=' + $examLevel,
            success:function(results){
                //alert(results);
                jQuery("#exam_subject").removeAttr("disabled");       
                jQuery("#exam_subject").append(results);  
            }
    });                                    
});
```

It doesn't work with iOS devices for some reason. Does anybody know of a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving `.on('blur', function(e) { /* ... */ });` a shot. I think that Safari doesn't do `onchange` events with selects